# Is it possible to use a C library in background service for an android app?

Tags: android, c, service

I have a library written in C which I want to use in an android application. Is it possible to use this library in background service for the app? Can NDK be used for this? Or is there any other method available?

Comment: "Is it possible to use this library in background service for the app" -- yes. Whether it will work or not would depend upon the library. "Can NDK be used for this?" -- yes, the NDK is used for adding C/C++ code to an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a fresher in `JNI with Android`  , try to learn some basics like `HelloWorld` programs .

You will get JNI [example 1](https://github.com/donchakkappan/JNI-with-Android) , [example 2](https://github.com/donchakkappan/Date-Time-Using-JNI---Android) .

You need to setup [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to compile all of your `native codes`